# Responsive Vaadin Flow Grid

Tags: responsive-design, vaadin, vaadin-flow

The grid is a nice table that fits well for wide screens like desktop or tablet. However, when showing on smaller mobile device the grid will not fit with more than a few columns. How did you solve this problem in your application?

The table stack pattern sounds promising: https://responsivedesign.is/patterns/data-table-stack/
But how could I implement this with Vaadin Flow? Is there a possibility to exchange the grid with an item list depending on the screen size?

Comment: Broken link. ☹️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common approach is to have separate columns for mobile and desktop.

On mobile, or other narrow screens, there might only be one column in a stacking manner. This is quite simple to do with template renders, and a template along the lines of

```
<div>Name: [[item.name]]</div><div>E-mail: [[item.email]]</div>"
```

It's even possible to define the template as a Polymer template web component, import it, and set a template renderer like this

```
<mobile-column item="[[item]]"></mobile-column>
```

To toggle columns, one can add a resize listener (preferably throttled), e.g. as defined [here](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.9/com/vaadin/flow/dom/DomListenerRegistration.html#throttle-int-).

The [MediaQuery](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/mediaquery/overview) add-on is also very useful for this. I recommend toggling the visibility on the server, to avoid sending unnecessary data and doing unnecessary rendering in the browser.

Comment: There is even a code sample in the add-on page for exactly this usecase - toggling visibility of a column based on a media query. I was not aware of this MediaQuery Add-on, it looks great!

Comment: That add-on looks promising in conjunction with hiding columns and extending rows based on media queries. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would go with media queries. There is an example here to include them in styles : [Media queries in Shadow dom](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17705088/how-to-write-media-queries-in-shadow-dom)

So, for example, in case width is less than some pre-defined value, set `visibility` of grid to `hidden` and `list` to `visible` and vice versa, when needed.

Edit: there is also an add-on which might help in using queries : [Mediaquery](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/mediaquery/overview)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the add-on looks promising.